# Creating a flow chart including images

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to create a flow chart like the following attached one including images inside. How can I do this?

[image: flow chart with pictures]

Comment: What's the meaning of the thin blue lines? Do they represent zoomed portions?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I think so too.

Comment: @Alenanno I updated with an example using `\spy`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Update

If the thin blue lines represent zooming on the images, the `spy` library could be used:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta,spy}

\definecolor{arrowblue}{RGB}{98,145,224}

\newcommand\ImageNode[3][]{
  \node[draw=arrowblue!80!black,line width=1pt,#1] (#2) {\includegraphics[width=1.5cm,height=1.5cm]{#3}};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  spy using outlines={
    magnification=4, 
    size=1.5cm, 
    connect spies
  },
  node distance=1.5cm,
  >={Triangle[angle=60:1pt 2]},
  shorten >= 2pt,
  shorten <= 2pt,
  arrow/.style={
    ->,
    arrowblue,
    line width=5pt
  },
  aux/.style={
    text width=1.5cm,
    minimum height=1.75cm,
    draw=arrowblue!80!black,
    line width=1pt
  }
]
\ImageNode[label={-90:text}]{A}{example-image-a}
\node[right=of A,aux,label={270:text}] (B) {};
\spy[arrowblue] on ([shift={(0,-10pt)}]C) in node at (B) {};
\ImageNode[label={180:text},above right=of B]{C}{example-image-c}
\ImageNode[label={0:text},below right=of C]{D}{example-image}
\ImageNode[label={180:text},below left=of D]{E}{example-grid-100x100bp}
\node[right=of E,aux,label={0:text}] (F) {};
\spy[arrowblue] on ([shift={(10pt,0pt)}]E) in node at (F) {};
\node[below=of E,aux,label={270:text}] (G) {};
\spy[arrowblue] on ([shift={(0pt,10pt)}]E) in node at (G) {};
\ImageNode[left=of G]{H}{example-image}
\ImageNode[right=of G]{I}{example-image-a}

\draw[arrow]
  (A) -- node[above,text=black] {text} (B);
\draw[arrow]
  (C) -- (D);
\draw[arrow]
  (D) -- (E);
\draw[arrow]
  (G) -- (H);
\draw[arrow]
  (G) -- (I);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Initial version

One option:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta}

\definecolor{arrowblue}{RGB}{98,145,224}

\newcommand\ImageNode[3][]{
  \node[draw=arrowblue!80!black,line width=1pt,#1] (#2) {\includegraphics[width=1.5cm,height=1.5cm]{#3}};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=1.5cm,
  >={Triangle[angle=60:1pt 2]},
  shorten >= 2pt,
  shorten <= 2pt,
  arrow/.style={
    ->,
    arrowblue,
    line width=5pt
  }
]
\ImageNode[label={-90:text}]{A}{example-image-a}
\ImageNode[label={-90:text},right=of A]{B}{example-image-b}
\ImageNode[label={180:text},above right=of B]{C}{example-image-c}
\ImageNode[label={0:text},below right=of C]{D}{example-image}
\ImageNode[label={180:text},below left=of D]{E}{example-image-a}
\ImageNode[label={0:text},right=of E]{F}{example-image-b}
\ImageNode[label={-90:text},below=of E]{G}{example-image-c}
\ImageNode[left=of G]{H}{example-image}
\ImageNode[right=of G]{I}{example-image-a}

\draw[arrow]
  (A) -- (B);
\draw[arrow]
  (C) -- (D);
\draw[arrow]
  (D) -- (E);
\draw[arrow]
  (G) -- (H);
\draw[arrow]
  (G) -- (I);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Images are included using a `\node` using a command

```
\ImageNode[<node options>]{<node name>}{<image file>}
```

Comment: I wasn't sure about the meaning of the thin blue lines in the original diagram, so I didn't draw them.

Comment: Is there a way to make different size of \ImageNode?