# Arranging images besides a flowchart

Tags: graphics, lyx

I am not sure if this level of customization is allowed in Lyx, I want to to arrange few graphs beside my flow chart. all the graphs and the flow chart are in pdf format.

all the graphs are in 2" x 2" and the flow chart is scaled 3" x 10"

Pdf:
[image]

Lyx:

[image]

I want these 4 graphs to appear next to those 4 boxes in the flow chart. Any help in the type setting will be helpful

Final Edit:
Thanks to @Torbjørn T, I have completed the code.

Tikz code:

```
\tikzstyle{startstop} =[ ellipse, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw = black,  fill =white!30]
\tikzstyle{process} =[ rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2cm,text centered, draw = black,  fill =white!30] 
\tikzstyle{arrow} =[ thick, ->, >=stealth]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4cm]
node/.append style={font=\Large}.
\node(start) [startstop] {Start}; 
\node(pro1) [process, below of=start] {Step 1}; 

\node(pro2) [process, below of=pro1, align=center] {Step 2}; 

\node(pro3) [process, below of=pro2, align=center] {Step 3}; 

\node(pro4) [process, below of=pro3, align=center] {Step 4}; 

\node(stop) [startstop, below of =pro4] {Stop};

\node[inner sep=0pt,right = 3mm of pro1](img1) {\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{test.pdf}}; 
\node[inner sep=0pt, left=3mm of pro2](img2) {\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{test.pdf}}; 
\node[inner sep=0pt,right = 3mm of pro3](img3) {\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{test.pdf}}; 
\node[inner sep=0pt,left = 3mm of pro4](img4) {\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{test.pdf}}; 

\foreach \i in {1,2,3,4}
    \draw [arrow] (pro\i) -- (img\i);

every node/.append style= {front=\Large}
\draw [arrow] (start) -- (pro1); 
\draw [arrow] (pro1) -- (pro2); 
\draw [arrow] (pro2) -- (pro3); 
\draw [arrow] (pro3) -- (pro4); 
\draw [arrow] (pro4) -- (stop);


\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Did you try settings the width of the minipages to 45% of the Line width or Text width?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thank you! that was the problem. Now they look kind of proper, but alleging them to the respective block is kind of problem.

Comment: I have no idea what you meant by that last sentence.

Comment: I have 4 graphs(4 Separate pdf) and 1 flowchart(1 pdf), which has 4 steps in it. each step(step 1, step 2, step 3, step 4) is represented by 1 graph. i want to have a graph next to each step. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Reduce the size of the four plots a bit and you should be fine I suppose. Or just leave them as is, and possibly add a label inside each axis (*Step 1*, *Step 2*, etc. Do that in whatever program you used to generate the plots.), and explain in the caption that the four plots correspond to the four steps in the chart between `Start` and `End`.

Comment: your 2nd option was what i thought at first, but just wanted to ask suggestion over here. reducing the size of the 4 plot does not seem efficient. As nothing is visible if i reduce the plot more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46575/discussion-between-torbjorn-t-and-aashu10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suggestion for TikZ code placing images next to a simple flowchart (via [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46575/discussion-between-torbjorn-t-and-aashu10)).

In LyX, add

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta,shapes.geometric}
```

to Document --> Settings --> LaTeX Preamble.

In the document, add everything from (and including) `\begin{tikzpicture}` to `\end{tikzpicture}` in an ERT (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, or Insert -> TeX Code). Note that if you copy-paste code such as that below into an ERT, you should use Edit -> Paste special to preserve line breaks.

Adjust the various lengths to suit.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=1cm,
  startstop/.style={
       ellipse,
       minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,
       text centered,
       draw = black, fill =white!30,
       font={\Large}
  },
  process/.style={
       rectangle,
       minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,
       text centered,
       draw = black, fill=white,
       font={\Large}
  },
  arrow/.style={
       thick, ->, >=Stealth
  }] 

\node(start) [startstop] {Start}; 
\node(pro1) [process, below=of start] {Step 1}; 
\node(pro2) [process, below=of pro1] {Step 2}; 
\node(pro3) [process, below=of pro2] {Step 3}; 
\node(pro4) [process, below=of pro3] {Step 4}; 
\node(stop) [process, below=of pro4] {Stop}; 

\begin{scope}[node distance=1cm, every node/.style={inner sep=0pt}]
\node [left=of pro1] (img1) {\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}}; 
\node [right=of pro2] (img2) {\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image-a}}; 
\node [left=of pro3] (img3) {\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image-b}}; 
\node [right=of pro4] (img4) {\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image-c}}; 
\end{scope}

\foreach \i in {1,2,3,4}
  % modify the shorten value to whatever you like
  \draw [dotted,shorten >=2mm,shorten <=2mm] (pro\i) -- (img\i);

\foreach [remember=\x as \y (initially start)] \x in {pro1,pro2,pro3,pro4,stop}
  \draw [arrow] (\y) -- (\x);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two `minipage` side by side will solve the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[c]{.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=12cm]{example-image}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}\\
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}\\
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}\\
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Example}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Pretty new to latex, How do i do this in Lyx?

Comment: @Aashu10 No idea, I've never used Lyx.

Comment: @Aashu10 Insert -> Box -> Frameless inserts a `minipage`, then you need to edit its Settings to set the vertical alignment to center.

Comment: @Ignasi I have edited my question with the code, it does not work.

Comment: @Aashu10 "It does not work", what does it mean? Do you have any error? the result is not as expected? ...

Comment: @Aashu10 Are you using `twocolumn` format? Could you show us a minimal code, from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`?

Comment: @Ignasi, sorry my bad. Had wrong width setting. I have attached the source code and the fig. Can you help me adjust the fig properly. suck that step1 corresponds to 1st graph?

Comment: @Aashu10 are you trying to make the first box correspond to the first step and the second box correspond to the second step and so on?

Comment: Yes! Let me explain in detail.  
I have 4 graphs(4 Separate pdf) and 1 flowchart(1 pdf), which has 4 steps in it. each step(step 1, step 2, step 3, step 4) is represented by 1 graph. i want to have a graph next to each step. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @Aashu10 while this is certainly possible, it depends on how much effort you want to put in. You can use `\vspace{}` in order to add vertical spaces around your boxes or you can go the full nine miles and recreate everything in Tikz or equivalent plotting package.

Comment: I am confident of making a Tikz diagram of the flowchart, but I am clueless of the graphs beside it. I have the graphs in pdf format right now(exported from matlab)

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, the end result is for images to be 'in line' with the various boxes. One possible solution is manually using `\vspace` until the boxes are in line with each other. While *not* ideal and time consuming if any changes are made to the flow chart, it is possible (see image below).

[image]

If Tikz code for the flow chart is posted, then I/other users will be happy to help you positioning images next to the flow chart. Images would be inserted like:

```
\node[inner sep=0pt] (test) at (0,0)
{\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{test.jpg}};
```

There will be plenty of resources out there regarding inserting images into a Tikz picture. If you intend to create a fully customisable figure then I would recommend this path!

EDIT: For example: [Creating a flow chart including images](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254548/creating-a-flow-chart-including-images)

EDIT2: Added code copy and pasted from LyX (yes not great especially LyX's use of center environments as I didn't use `ctrl + enter` for `\\`, but asked for in the comments):

```
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}
\begin{centering}
\begin{minipage}[c][1\totalheight][t]{0.48\columnwidth}%
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\columnwidth]{\string"Flow Chart\string".eps}
\par\end{center}%
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[c][1\totalheight][t]{0.48\columnwidth}%
\vspace{0.4cm}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.56\columnwidth]{\string"Flow Chart Sample\string".jpg}
\par\end{center}
\vspace{-0.2cm}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.56\columnwidth]{\string"Flow Chart Sample\string".jpg}
\par\end{center}
\vspace{-0.2cm}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.56\columnwidth]{\string"Flow Chart Sample\string".jpg}
\par\end{center}%
\end{minipage}
\par\end{centering}
\caption{Sample}
\end{figure}
\par\end{center}
```

Comment: I have a question regarding picture, when I put 2 box(frameless), they appear 1 below the other in lyx. But they appear besides each other in your. Can you please post your code generated by lyx here. I want to check the settings.

Comment: @Aashu10, done - sorry for the delay

Comment: I was trying to draw the entire thing with tikz, I have edited my question with the code. >I could not add those graphs using \includegraphics. and i want to scale up the overall size of the graphsto fit 1 entire page. would be glad if you could help me out.